# How to add in a break code if there are no values that meet criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that checks if two fields meet a certain criteria and then move those records to an archive to help keep the main spreadsheet working fairly quickly.

It works great if there are any records to copy across, but throws an error if there aren't any.... in which case I get the message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Is there a way to get the code to just end if there aren't any matches?

```js
function ArchiveRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking Data'); //source sheet
  const dt = new Date();
  //Value [60] below represents 60 days ago
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 60).valueOf();
  var StatusRange = sh.getRange('N1:N' + sh.getLastRow()); //Status column
  var DueDateRange = sh.getRange('I1:I' + sh.getLastRow()); //DueDate column
  var StatusValue = StatusRange.getValues().flat();
  var DueDateValue = DueDateRange.getValues().flat();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Historical'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j = [];
  for (i = 0; i < StatusValue.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(DueDateValue[i]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      if (StatusValue[i] == 'Returned' || StatusValue[i] == 'Returned by Post' || StatusValue[i] == 'RUD') {
        data.push.apply(data, sh.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 19).getValues());
        //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
        j.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  //Copy data array to destination sheet

  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  //Delete matched rows in source sheet
  for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    var k = j[i] + 1;
    sh.deleteRow(k);

    //Alter j to account for deleted rows
    if (!(i == j.length - 1)) {
      j[i + 1] = j[i + 1] - i - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) In which line you get the undefined error. There are more than 6 lines that use the length method. 2) which variable can be empty and you think it causes the error?

Comment: @soMarios Obviously the `data`/`data[0]` array when attempting to copy lol

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it this way:

```
function ArchiveRows() {
  const sA = ["Returned","Returned by Post","RUD"]
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking Data');
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 60).valueOf();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Historical');
  var data = [];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if(new Date(r[8]).valueOf() < dtv && ~sA.indexOf(r[13]) ) {
      data.push(r)
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    }
  });
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```